# ngmap for markers in google map

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I am using ngmap and angularjs to generate points on a google map. I works perfectly on my local server, but when you move to a production server does not display the map. Seeing the console see the following error: "Error: google is not defined"

My code:

```js
    var app = angular.module('dataview', ['ngMap'])
    app.controller('DataViewCtrl', function($scope, $http)
    {
      $scope.markers[{lat:30.2817, lng:-81.5273},{lat:30.6824, lng:-81.9680},{lat:31.0004, lng:-82.1580}];

      $scope.mapcenter={lat:$scope.markers[0].lat, lng:$scope.markers[0].lng};
    }
```

```html
  <script src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'></script>
 <script src = '/assets/vendor/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js'></script>
    <map center="{{mapcenter.lat}}, {{mapcenter.lng}}" zoom="5" ng-if="is_map" style="height: 500px;">
        <marker ng-repeat="pos in markers" position="{{pos.lat}}, {{pos.lng}}"></marker>
    </map>
```

Comment: The error is <script src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'></script>. The production server is in https enviroment. The soluction: <script src = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'></script>. HTTPS in src, not HTTP

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src = '/assets/vendor/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js'></script>
```

is referencing a local asset.
Check that this file is available to the production server.

Comment: All resources are available on the server, otherwise I will obtain "injector error" and is not the case

Comment: Since you found the answer yourself, you are able to add an answer to your own question, then make it as the correct answer. I am not able to comment on the above stuff, because i don't have high enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

The error is: 
src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true. 
The production server is in https enviroment. 
The soluction: 
src = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true'. 
HTTPS not HTTP